# Show that matrices $A$ and $B$ commute if and only if $\begin{vmatrix} b & a-c \\ e & d-f\end{vmatrix}=0.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that the matrices 
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix} \text{and B = $\begin{bmatrix} d & e \\ 0 & f \end{bmatrix}$}$$ 
>   commute if and only if 
>   $$\begin{vmatrix} b & a-c \\ e & d-f\end{vmatrix}=0.$$

---

My approach:

For $AB=BA$, we must have  $AB=\begin{bmatrix} ad & ae+bf \\\ 0 & cf\end{bmatrix}$ and $BA=\begin{bmatrix} ad & bd+ce \\\ 0 & cf\end{bmatrix}$ where $ae+bf=bd+ce$. We need to show that if $ae+bf=bd+ce$ then $\begin{vmatrix} b & a-c \\ e & d-f\end{vmatrix}=0.$

Since $\begin{vmatrix} b & a-c \\ e & d-f\end{vmatrix}=0$, we see that: $$b(d-f)-e(a-c)=0 \iff bd-bf-ae+ce=0 \iff bd+ce=ae+bf.$$

Thus, if  $AB=BA$ then $\begin{vmatrix} b & a-c \\ e & d-f\end{vmatrix}=0.$

(Showing the converse)

If $\begin{vmatrix} b & a-c \\ e & d-f\end{vmatrix}=0$ then we have $bd+ce=ae+bf$ and $AB=BA$ if and only if $ae+bf=bd+ce$, which we have.

---

Is this a proper approach am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct. There are just some logically not well-organized statements.

Starting from here: "we need to show that if $ae+bf=bd+ce$ then $\begin{vmatrix} b & a-c \\ e & d-f\end{vmatrix}=0.$" This is what you stated. But what you showed was another way.

The "showing the converse" step should really be what you showed above that.

However, since your proof has two-way arrow in each step, it actually showed the "if and only if" statement. You only need to:

1. Remove the last part of "showing the converse";

2.Change your first statement to "we need to show that... if and only if ...";

3. Remove the "Since" before $\begin{vmatrix} b & a-c \\ e & d-f\end{vmatrix}=0$, put this equation after the "We see that", and add another two-way arrow after it.